# Redirect to another page when login based on condition in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a sample in spring boot in which first show login page and if login is correct then move to home page.

Their is one feature in which I send a mail with a link.On click of this link my login page is open in new window and if already login then move to that page which is specify in link.

Now my task is to when user is logged in with email link not from direct URL then home page is not open and the page which is specify in link is open.

In my requirement I am not able to understand that how I identify that login is from URL or email.

My code is -

**For mail -**

```
public void sendEmail() throws Exception{
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
        helper.setTo("abc@gmail.com");
        String content="<a href=\"http://localhost:8090/#/Report\">click here</a>";
        helper.setText("How are you?"+content,true);
        helper.setSubject("Hi");
        sender.send(message);
    }
```

**For Login -**

```
public void index(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            // get your file as InputStream
            InputStream is;
            if (request.getSession().getAttribute(API_KEY) != null) {//Here API_KEY set when logged in
                is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("public/index.html");
            }  else {
                is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("public/login.html");
            }

            // copy it to response's OutputStream
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.debug("Error writing file to output stream", ex);
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
    }
```